# HTML dashboard is disabled in Apache Hue

Tags: solr, hue

I have built Aapche hue in my ubuntu system using below link :

http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/

I am creating a dashboard by searching data from Apahce Solr.
In the dashboard there is a URL which I want to make clickable.
So I need to make changes through HTML. But the HTML part in dashboard is disabled as shown below :
[image]
Can some one tell me how to enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you already have the grid widget. You would need to delete it, then the HTML widget will be enabled.